# Automapper: Map to Protected Property

Tags: c#, automapper

I need to map to a `protected` property on a class using `Automapper`.  I've got a `public` method exposed on this class that is used to set values to the property. This method requires a `parameter`.  How can I map a value to this class?

Destination Class:

```
public class Policy
     {
         private Billing _billing;

         protected Billing Billing
             {
                get { return _billing; }
                set { _billing = value; }
             }

         public void SetBilling(Billing billing)
            {
                if (billing != null)
                {
                    Billing = billing;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NullReferenceException("Billing can't be null");
                }
            }
    }
```

Here's what my `Automapper` code (pseudo code) looks like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PolicyDetail, Policy>()
          .ForMember(d => d.SetBilling(???), 
                          s => s.MapFrom(x => x.Billing));
```

I need to pass a Billing class to the SetBilling(Billing billing) method.  How do I do this?  Or, can I just set the protected Billing property?

Comment: The 2 classes don't share very few of the same names for their properties.  So, the only way I know how to use Automapper for this is to use .ForMember.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easiest way: Use AfterMap/BeforeMap constructs.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PolicyDetail, Policy>()    
.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.SetBilling(src.Billing));
```

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Before-and-after-map-actions

Answer (score 18):

Also possible: tell AutoMapper to recognize protected members:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    // map properties with public or internal getters
    cfg.ShouldMapProperty = p => p.GetMethod.IsPublic || p.GetMethod.IsAssembly;
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
});
```

No extra AfterMap needed. AutoMapper by default looks for public properties, you have to tell it on a global or Profile basis to do something differently (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#configuring-visibility)

Comment: This is one of the reasons why SO is the best technical resource on the web.  Where else can you ask a question and have it answered by the person that wrote the software.

Comment: Which is more efficient?  Using AfterMap or configuration?

Comment: More efficient, or more obvious? I like to go with the more semantic approach. AfterMap is really the nuclear option, and is more error-prone.

Comment: Is there a non static way, using MapperConfiguration without using Profiles ?

Comment: @cdie well I didn't use profiles in my example. But that "cfg" thingy, it's the same thing passed in to the MapperConfiguration constructor. Just replace "Mapper.Initialize" with "new MapperConfiguration"

Comment: Actually Jimmy's example does not work for Protected properties. I found that c.ShouldMapProperty = p => p.GetGetMethod(true).IsPrivate || p.GetGetMethod(true).IsHideBySig; works.(http://codesnippets.fesslersoft.de/map-to-protected-property-using-automapper/)