# AutoMapper: How to Initialize BindingFlags?

Tags: c#, automapper

When I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568428/automapper-map-to-protected-property/27575083#27575083) about AutoMapper and `protected` properties, I received a response from [Jimmy Bogard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58508/jimmy-bogard) (AutoMapper co-creator).  He suggested that we can initialize the `BindingFlags` using the code that I pasted below.  The problem is, I get the following error and don't know how to fix it:

> "AutoMapper.IConfiguration does not contain a definition for
>   'BindingFlags' and no extension method..."

Here's the code:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.BindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
                cfg.CreateMap<PolicyDetail, Policy>();
            });
```

**UPDATE:**

I didn't have AutoMapper 3.3.0.  Once I updated, this code worked.  Thanks to Gert Arnold.

Comment: `BindingFlags` was added recently. It's in v 3.3.0.

Comment: @GertArnold...this is the answer, I didn't have the most recent version.

Comment: This has apparently been deprecated as of 3.3.1, so is there currently no way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it should work, looking at the source code, `IConfiguration` inherits from `IProfileExpression`, which inherits from `IMappingOptions`, which contains a public property with the following definition:

```
BindingFlags BindingFlags { get; set; }
```

See [AutoMapper > src > UnitTests > BindingFlagsConfiguration.cs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/d6eaf7025932ebedccbf8c339a155e9f4ae5c5d8/src/UnitTests/BindingFlagsConfiguration.cs) for an example to compare to what you have.